# Assigning a week number to a series of dates in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called Sales_Table which stores all the sales amongst our branches. The columns Sale_Date & Day_Number both record the day a transaction occurs in, as a date and a number respectively. I am in need of a query which assigns a week number, in a column titled something like Week_Number, to each of the dates. This needs to be done so that I can begin to investigate weekly sales. I am not particularly worried about whether the Sales_Date is used to fill in the Week_Number column or if you want to use the numbers in the Day_Number column to do it.

Thank you for taking the time to read this problem, it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

An ISO week is always Monday-Sunday and the first week of the iso-year is always counted as the first week that has the majority of its days in the year (so will always contain the 4th January as it will have at least 4 days of the year in the week). You can use the `IW` format model to get the ISO week and `IYYY` to get the iso-year.

If you want the week to always correspond to the calendar year then you can use the `WW` format model and the week will start from whatever day 1st January is.

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table ( sale_date ) AS
SELECT DATE '2019-12-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2019-12-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2019-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-17' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT sale_date,
       TO_CHAR( sale_date, 'IW' ) AS iso_week_number,
       TO_CHAR( sale_date, 'IYYY' ) AS iso_year,
       TO_CHAR( sale_date, 'WW' ) AS week_number,
       TO_CHAR( sale_date, 'DY' ) AS day_of_week
FROM   your_table
```

**Output**:

> ```
> SALE_DATE | ISO_WEEK_NUMBER | ISO_YEAR | WEEK_NUMBER | DAY_OF_WEEK
> :-------- | :-------------- | :------- | :---------- | :----------
> 29-DEC-19 | 52              | 2019     | 52          | SUN        
> 30-DEC-19 | 01              | 2020     | 52          | MON        
> 31-DEC-19 | 01              | 2020     | 53          | TUE        
> 01-JAN-20 | 01              | 2020     | 01          | WED        
> 04-JAN-20 | 01              | 2020     | 01          | SAT        
> 05-JAN-20 | 01              | 2020     | 01          | SUN        
> 06-JAN-20 | 02              | 2020     | 01          | MON        
> 07-JAN-20 | 02              | 2020     | 01          | TUE        
> 08-JAN-20 | 02              | 2020     | 02          | WED        
> 17-JAN-20 | 03              | 2020     | 03          | FRI
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=87bc3d9e92ee0e624d1847c3a75b38f8)*

Comment: @MenelaosBakopoulos Well spotted, made this answer a community wiki.